# Rails sometimes issues NoMethodError when calling an inherited method from an Engine controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, webrick

I'm writing a Rails application that consists on a main application and a mountable engine, and I'm having some trouble that is driving me nuts.

Rails randomly issues NoMethodError when calling a function defined in a main app's controller from an engine's controller.

So far, I've defined a controller in the main application from which controllers in the engine inherit. Below there's a summary of the directory structure, being "my_plugin" the engine's directory (code is also attached below).

I've noticed that when WEBrick is running, **if I just "touch" the `bar_controller.rb` file (i.e. save it with no modifications), then everything starts working fine**. It seems Rails sometimes doesn't load the parent classes properly during boot and touching the file makes it reload everything (sorry, I don't know how Rails works internally).

What am I doing wrong?

```
app
|- controllers
   |- foo_controller.rb
...
plugins
| - my_plugin
        | - app
             | - controllers
                 | - my_plugin
                     | - application_controller.rb
                     | - bar_controller.rb
```

The code in `foo_controller.rb` is:

```
class FooController < ActionController::Base  
    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

    private
        def my_function
            #...
        end
end
```

On the other hand, the code in my plugin's `application_controller.rb` is:

```
module MyPlugin  
  #Inherit from main's app FooController
  class ApplicationController < ::FooController
  end
end
```

Finally, the code in my plugin's `bar_controller.rb` is:

```
module MyPlugin
  class BarController < ApplicationController    
      def index
          #####################################################
          # The statement below issues NoMethodError until
          # I touch this file while WEBrick is running.
          #####################################################
          my_function
      end
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

I've noticed that the problem still persists if I define `my_function` in the plugin's `application_controller.rb` (see below) and don't inherit from `FooController`. So it seems the problem has nothing to do with inheritance from app's classes.

```
module MyPlugin        
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      private
          def my_function
               #...
          end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found myself the solution and I must say the way Rails works with engines and reacts to stupid situations is quite disappointing.

I have created a test model in my plugin **using rails scaffolding** and I've noticed that the generated controller has an extra code line at the top of the file that is not present in main application's controllers:

```
require_dependency "my_plugin/application_controller"
```

I manually created the `BarController` and therefore I didn't write that line (I wrongly relied on the 'Rails is magic' premise; Rails is no longer magic for me). Now, my questions are:

1. If **mountable Engines** are said to be like "**isolated Rails applications**", why must I change the way I write code for engines? Why do I have to explicitly tell Ruby to require that dependency? When I write controllers in the main application, Rails does "all the magic". Why doesn't it do the magic here too?
2. Is there a way to load such dependencies automatically when Rails loads the module?
3. If dependencies are required, why doesn't Rails issue an error when trying to inherit from an "unloaded class" instead of failing when trying to call an inherited method?

**EDIT**

See this discussion on [GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22098) for further information. All this stuff has to do with a Rails gotcha documented [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#when-constants-aren-t-missed).